# Removing whitespace and moving slideshow up to center of page

Tags: html, css, containers

I have a slideshow container I wish to host in the middle of the page, next to my navigation bar. Which would eliminate the extra white space. This is only behaving this way on my homepage and not the other pages; so I wish to keep it that way since the other pages are correctly placed.

Edit:
Sorry for not including the code earlier. When I originally attached it, it said it was incorrect. This is my first time using this site, so I apologize for messing up how it works.

Here's the slideshow's CSS

{box-sizing: border-box;}

```
 body {font-family: Times New Roman, sans-serif;}
    .mySlides {display: none;}
    img {vertical-align: middle;}
        
    /* Slideshow container */
    .slideshow-container {
    max-width: fit-content;
    max-height: fit-content;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 40px;
    margin-right: auto;}
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please take the [tour] and read the [ask] page for tips on how to improve this question.  For starters, please include a [mre] of the issue you need help with for faster troubleshooting.  We cannot debug screenshots of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you forgot to add `top: 0;` to your `.slideshow-container` since it has an absolute position in css.

If your `.slideshow-container` is directly next to your navbar/header. Then, your top value should be the height of the navbar/header.

Answer (score -1):

Link you've sent works is local and works only on your computer.

You probably need to look into css properties such as object-fit and combine it with proper positioning and scaling.

See this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit and probably this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Positioning

Feel free to ask more questions, or provide some code

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).